# Why is unattended-upgrades activated by default?

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, lts

I just migrated from CentOS to Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. I chose "no" when it asked me to do automatic updates during the setup. However, I just realized that by default unattended-upgrades is activated and installed by default, since it had installed a kernel update automatically. This is very Windows like and is disappointing me. Why is this the case that it is enabled by default even though the user chose no during the setup?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the setup is asking to download updates during the setup so it installs updates packages, not about activating or not "unattended-upgrades".

Comment: I was about to ask exactly that, it's like I have to remember for every fresh new xbuntu installation that I have to disable them.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342663/how-is-unattended-upgrades-started-and-how-can-i-modify-its-schedule and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470709/how-do-i-stop-disable-unattended-upgrades-from-being-launched-automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain why it gives you the option and then ignores your response.  Without installing, I can't confirm that behaviour, however, it's easy to fix it.

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and comment out the `-security` line.

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Comment: Good rule of thumb when overriding in `conf.d` areas: Better to always create a custom override file when possible. `99z-custom` would work in this area I think (untested). When apt updates itself your `50unattended-upgrades` files might be overwritten. Your custom file will not.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to disable unattended upgrades is to

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-updates` and set "Unattended-Upgrade" to "0".

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Comment: Isn't that file called `20auto-upgrades`, not `20auto-updates`?

Comment: Files from linux's *.d folders are read in alphanumeric order irrespective of their exact name. Thus, the answer will work as long as the name is alphanumerically bigger than "10periodic".

Comment: @wedi Yes - and this should be taken advantage of. It avoids a package overwriting your changes on system updates. You have to make sure when using any `conf.d` area that your custom directive(s) come LAST. The filename `20auto-updates` if used as user-created new override file, would be read in BEFORE `20auto-upgrades`. Last file read wins. Better idea on any `conf.d` area is to create something you know will be read DEAD LAST. Try creating `99z-custom` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` with the statement `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";` - it will be read last. Again: Last wins.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use: `dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`

Comment: Correct. This also sets `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` and `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`.