# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS What Job Updates /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Tags: grub2, cron, systemd, systemd-journald

I have just set up a new, stripped down Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, with ***automatic updates turned off***. Over the weekend it mysteriously updated /boot/grub/grub.cfg, which started a whole bunch of kernel threads and a few daemons that I don't want/need running (like metad etc - disabled in systemd).

Looking at the system logs and journalctl shows when this happened but not what actually caused update-grub or equivalent to run. I've looked through systemctl and the cron job directories looking for possible job files but nothing stands out.

1. What job does this unattended update-grub?
2. Are there better logs or tools for finding out what is running this job?

Many thanks in advance,

John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the `unattended-upgrades` may be running. See [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785339/why-is-unattended-upgrades-activated-by-default).

Also check `/var/log/unattended-upgrades` for activity from that tool.

See  `/var/log/apt/history.log` for a history of package upgrades your system.

Comment: Many thanks for that. It was that. Despite turning off unattended updates in the installer it still did it which is a change form 14.04. Grrr. I have commented out the repo sections in 50unattended-upgrades as I do want to be reminded of updates when I log in. Then I can schedule and outage when it's convenient. Many thanks :-).